# wicked_pdf (with wkhtmltopdf) doesn’t render Font Awesome icons

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, pdf

I’m trying to convert an existing html document with Font Awesome icons included in pdf. I use [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) for this task. But obviously is creating a pdf some very hard task.
All Font Awesome Icons are replaced with blanks. I need some advise to make things work.

My configuration:

- wicked_pdf (1.1.0)
- wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge (0.12.4.0)

The generated html looks like this:

```
<p>
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> &nbsp; +49 123 4567890
</p>
```

The controller action for creating the pdf:

```rb
def create_pdf
  @presenter = PortfolioPDFPresenter.new(@portfolio, self)
  html = render_to_string(template: 'portfolios/pdf_templates/portfolio',
                          layout: 'pdf_layout')
  footer_html = render_to_string(template: 'portfolios/pdf_templates/footer',
                                 layout: 'pdf_layout')
  title = ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(@portfolio.heading.html_safe, tags: [])

  pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html,
                                      title:              title,
                                      author:             current_user.fullname,
                                      page_size:          'A4',
                                      margin:             { top: 20, bottom: 40 },
                                      print_media_type:   true,
                                      dpi:                600,
                                      zoom:               1,
                                      no_pdf_compression: false,
                                      lowquality:         false,
                                      outline:            { outline: true, outline_depth: 4 },
                                      footer:             { content: footer_html },
                                      extra:              '--encoding UTF8 --disable-smart-shrinking')

  send_data(pdf,
            filename: "#{t('activerecord.models.portfolio.one')}-#{current_user.fullname}.pdf",
            disposition: 'attachment',
            type: :pdf)
end # create_pdf
```

And finally the layout:

```
!!!
%html{lang: "#{I18n.locale.to_s}"}
  %head
    %meta{ content: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'http-equiv': 'Content-Type' }
    %meta{ name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no' }
    %meta{ 'http-equiv': 'Accept-CH', content: 'DPR, Viewport-Width, Width' }
    %title
      = t('app_title')
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,700'
    = stylesheet_link_tag    wicked_pdf_asset_base64("pdf_styles"), media: 'print'
    = stylesheet_link_tag    wicked_pdf_asset_base64("pdf_styles")
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'

  %body
    #main-content
      = yield
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar issue myself. First I wasn't getting any icons and then subsequently, I started getting a weird W-on-top-of-M kind of icon.

#### Not getting any icons

Was resolved once I added the absolute CDN path to Font awesome to my pdf layout file.
https://github.com/brunzino/wpdf-icon-debug/pull/1/files?diff=split

#### Getting a weird *W-on-top-of-M* icon

This wasn't a problem on the server (Ubuntu 16.04). As in, the icon showed correctly on the production site. However on my Mac all icons were replaced by this strange icon. Never really resolved it but read somewhere that this gets resolved by installing the ttf font on the Mac.

Hope this helps